# 19.04 distribution upgrade hang

Tags: 19.04, partial-upgrade

I'm doing a partial upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS to 19.04 using the Do-partial-upgrade tool on a Dell XPS 15. The installation froze while configuring Linux:
[image]
Is it safe to cancel the installation and does anyone have any suggestions for how to get it to succeed?

Answer (score 0):

I wound up killing the Distribution Upgrade process with xkill, switching to intel graphics, following the instructions [here](https://itsfoss.com/could-not-get-lock-error/) to remove locks, then running:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

And it looks like everything is working after a restart.